# Could not load type 'PrintMan.MvcApplication'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am making my very first asp.net project live and running into what I assume is configuration options. Note that there are similiar threads on StackOverflow regarding this but I have already gone through those answers but no success.

The project is working perfectly in my dev environment but on the production server it fails to work. I have restarted IIS, I have currently only this site in the config and the namespace is correct.

Having limited experience in this I am hoping someone can explain what the underlying issue is :)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PrintMan.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="PrintMan.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>


Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274
```

Comment: If you navigate your FTP folder, can you confirm Global.asax.cs is there?

Comment: I can, it's in the root of my site. Could this perhaps be permissions?

Comment: A few questions: Did you rename your project, at some point? What is your output path?

Comment: I may have renamed it at the start, but cannot remember to be honest, and my output path is bin\

Comment: This usually happens when the project is not built or the dlls are missing. Did you copy all dlls from your bin folder to the server?